Why the services are not shown in Eureka?
I have written code for the Eureka client, but it does not show any of my services on Eureka. What could be causing this issue? It seems like despite implementing the necessary configurations, my services are not being registered with the Eureka server.
Could this be due to a mistake in my Eureka client setup, such as incorrect service registration settings or an invalid Eureka server URL? I have made sure that the @EnableEurekaClient annotation is present in my Spring Boot application, but still, no luck. Could there be a network issue preventing the communication between my client and the Eureka server?
pom.xml of service:
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
  </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>

application.properties of discovery:
spring.application.name=ServiceRegistry
eureka.instance.hostname= localhost
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

pom.xml of discovery:
    <groupId>com.demo.serviceregistry</groupId>
    <artifactId>ServiceRegistry</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ServiceRegistry</name>
    <description>This is project that implement service registry</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>


application.properties of services :
server.port=8082

spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/microservices?sessionVariables=sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'&jdbcCompliantTruncation=false
spring.datasource.username=****
spring.datasource.password=*******

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

# Hibernate properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8080/eureka


Please help me resolve this issue.

I didn't find any issues in discovery application.properties file.
but in service application.properties I found some fields missing.
base application.yml for your reference

